# How to convert 'Mar 14' string format date into date i.e.2014-03-01(03 month, 01 date)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

How to convert 'Mar 2014' string format date into date i.e.2014-03-01(03 month, 01 date)??

```
Declare 

declare @StartDate  datetime,
Delcare @DateFrom varchar(10) SET @DateFrom = 'Mar 13'
**EXPECTED RESULT SHOULD BE:** 2014-03-01

set @EndDate = (SELECT dateadd(month, datediff(month, '19000101',@DateFrom), '19000101'))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of typo mistake in the code. Check again

```
declare @StartDate  datetime
declare @DateFrom varchar(10) 
SET @DateFrom = 'Mar 2013'
select Convert(date,@DateFrom)
```

Comment: `select Convert(date,@DateFrom)` gives you `2013-03-01`